# Scandic letters with UTF-8 are not working in JSF-MYSQL-PrimeFaces-software?

Tags: validation, utf-8, character-encoding

I am outside like snowman in the winter. I set ALTER SCHEMA `happyend`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ; to my MySQL DB.

In my xhtml-page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I have problems with scandic letters like ÄÖÅ. If I insert them straight to db, everything is working fine even I watch that property from the form in web browser they are ok. BUT if edit the property in the web browser, then they are like that: ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ. Is this something with validation or what the heck is doing that. I have tried to figure that out two days now and I have no idea anymore.

Comment: Sorry, there's just not enough information to go on here.

Comment: Looks vaguely like UTF8 mojibake; for example, the UTF8 encoding for ä is Ã¤ when viewed as Latin-1, and ö is Ã¶.

Comment: What does it mean UTF mojibake? I got exactly what you said. I added line of code to my filter and now it is working, but I still have no idea what caused that, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code to insert data in database.

create database using "create database databasename default charset utf8 collate utf8_bin;"

```
String unicode= "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        PreparedStatement p1=null;
        cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsfdb"+unicode, "root", "root");
```

it will surely work.

Comment: Hi!Thanks for answering. I didn't try that yet but I added to my filter one line of code where I tell to every request to use UTF-8 and it is working. DB is working fine then and driver as well I think, so I am still out and now idea what is causing this :) httpRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");